# Java: Use of bootclasspath preventing H2 driver from being found

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, classnotfoundexception, bootclasspath

If I build my own, tinkered version of `rt.jar` (called `my-rt.jar`) from the Oracle JDK 7 sources and hook it in with the `bootclasspath` mechanism, like this,

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/my-rt.jar -cp /path/to/h2-1.3.174.jar main
```

then, I can't even load the H2 driver at the beginning of my application:

```
// Application's main.java
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");      // Line 145

    }

}
```

The above results in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/h2/Driver
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at main.main(main.java:415)
```

However, if I remove the `-Xbootclasspath/p` switch and with everything else the same as before, I can load the driver fine, and the rest of application too works fine too.

So, is there anything peculiar going on inside the initialization of a JDBC driver (such as H2's) that's preventing me from using the bootclasspath mechanism? Or, is there anything peculiar about the `bootclasspath` mechanism that it won't allow the loading of a JDBC driver like H2?

I'm out of things to try. For example,

1. I've even re-built the H2 driver from its sources and made sure that both my application and the driver are using the identical version of `javac`.
2. I've tried the above both from Eclipse and from command-line.
3. I've tried it on 2 different machines.

All yield the same exception.

Btw, my tinkered `my-rt.jar` has a very simple edit to it: It simply adds a `public static int counter` to `java.lang.Object`. Before the `Class.forName(...)` line above, I'm able to verify that I can indeed print the value of `counter` when the `bootclasspath` switch is enabled.

The strange thing is, even if I comment out this `counter` field in `java.lang.Object` but  continue prepending `my-rt.jar` (that is as good as the original `rt.jar`, only recompiled andn prepended), even then I cannot get the H2 driver to be found/loaded!

*(I've [posted this on the H2 google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/bTyHMLo1zeI) too but getting no response there. Maybe, those folks don't think this is an H2 problem, so I'm asking here.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've nailed it. Here's what I did.

I first prepended the *original* `rt.jar` to the *original* `rt.jar`, like so:

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/orig/rt.jar -cp /path/to/h2-1.3.174.jar main
```

And the exception disappeared! This clearly told me that the `bootclasspath/p` mechanism was no way interfering with the loading of the H2 driver.

So, I then unjarred the original `rt.jar` and `diff`'ed it with the unjarred contents of `my-rt.jar`, I found around a whopping 8000 files missing from `my-rt.jar`:

```
$ wc -l *.list
  11285 my-rt.jar.list
  19059 rt.jar.list
  30344 total
```

So, obviously, `my-rt.jar` that I built from the official `src.zip` had tons of stuff missing from it. No wonder, H2 driver was having loading troubles.

To further confirm, this time I copied over only my tinkered `java/lang/Object.class` to the unjarred contents of the original `rt.jar`, and lo and behold, the  H2 driver continued to load just fine.

Thus, the name `src.zip` is a terrible misnomer. Because it does not have everything needed to build `rt.jar`, it should be called `partial-src.zip` (or, something like that) instead.

Comment: AFAIK the src.zip doesn't contain (some or all of) the proprietary classes in the `sun.*`, `com.sun.*` and `com.oracle.*` packages.

Comment: And I learned that the hard way. Was easy to miss that because of the name. As I said, clearer names for this zip could have been: `partial-src.zip`, `nonproprietary-src.zip`, `publicOnly-src.zip`, etc.